# How can I convert Tensorflow frozen graph to TF Lite model?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am using [Faster RCNN](https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN), repo that I am using can be found in the link, to detect cars in a video frame. I used Keras 2.2.3 and Tensorflow 1.15.0. I want to deploy and run it on my Android device. Each part in Faster RCNN is implemented in Keras and in order to deploy it on Android I want to convert them to TF Lite model. The final network, the classifier, has a custom layer which is called RoiPoolingConv and I cannot convert the final network to TF Lite. At first, I have tried the following

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('model_classifier_with_architecture.h5',
                custom_objects={"RoiPoolingConv": RoiPoolingConv})
tfmodel = converter.convert()
open ("model_cls.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

This gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Keras-FasterRCNN/model_to_tflite.py", line 26, in <module>
    custom_objects={"RoiPoolingConv": RoiPoolingConv})
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 747, in from_keras_model_file
    keras_model = _keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom_objects)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 212, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 192, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1131, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1089, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 475, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1441, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

As a workaround I tried was to convert Keras models to Tensorflow frozen graph and then do the TF Lite conversion on these frozen graphs. This yields the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alp/.local/bin/toco_from_protos", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 59, in main
    app.run(main=execute, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/alp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 33, in execute
    output_str = tensorflow_wrap_toco.TocoConvert(model_str, toco_str, input_str)
Exception: We are continually in the process of adding support to TensorFlow Lite for more ops. It would be helpful if you could inform us of how this conversion went by opening a github issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?template=40-tflite-op-request.md
 and pasting the following:

Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you might be able to use the extended runtime by passing --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are using: ADD, CAST, CONCATENATION, CONV_2D, DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D, FULLY_CONNECTED, MUL, PACK, RESHAPE, RESIZE_BILINEAR,   SOFTMAX, STRIDED_SLICE. Here is a list of operators for which you will need custom implementations: AddV2.
```

Is there a way to achieve the conversion of model with custom layer to TF Lite model?

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35901

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you so much for pointing me to that issue. I tried the workaround I mentioned in the question on my Colab environment and it worked. Now I have the .tflite file. It seems as if it is a version conflict between my Colab environment and local environment.